# Xcode12 beta4: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for free standing

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode12

In Xcode12 beta4 or beta5, I encounter a failure in my project.
I can run the Project on my device, but it is not running in the simulator.

I get the failure message:
ld: in /libwebrtc.a(dequantizemmx.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for free standing, file 'libwebrtc.a' for architecture x8664.

So does anyone know what settings should be adjusted in Xcode 12.4?

Answer (score -1):

### Response from Apple on similar issue.

You’ll need a few changes to support the new Xcode.

1. Package your framework using XCFrameworks.
2. Don’t install your SDK into the iOS SDK. Your users should drag drop the XCFramework into their project.